# child query SOQL querymore in SOAP API?

Tags: soql, soap-api, query, governorlimits

we are using connection.query to get parent and child relationship records through the soap API. In some cases, our child query should return more than 200 records. Salesforce says that in Apex we should do a for loop to avoid the exception; however, we are using C# against the SOAP API queryResult where we add recs of childresult into an array. The array length only gets to 200.

How do we get the next 200 or avoid the exception when there are more than 200 children records?.

Querymore only works for parent query results, NOT child results.

Answer (score 1):

When we removed all __r references in the **parent query**, the child query returned all results. Not sure why SF would undo the limiting effect by this, but this resolved the limit in the child query. Note: child query had __r fields in them, but child query returned all rows with or without them.